# How can I change the default SharpDevelop libraries?

Tags: sharpdevelop

Every time I start a new solution, SharpDevelop always uses only the "system" library,
Can I change this?
By what I saw quickly in the settings gives only to change the header...

Comment: Hi Max, welcome to Stackoverflow, I edited your question.  Here at stackoverflow you don't have to make excuses for questions. It's appreciated when you immediatly cut to te meat of the question.  If the community desides that it is not a good question, it will receive some down votes, so that the good questions stay findable for others with the same problem as you are suffering.  (That's the only consequence, and don't see down votes as an attack to your person.)  Welcome, success finding an answer to this question and I hope to see you arround.

Comment: That's because the project template was designed that way. Unless you create tons of new projects daily, manually adding the references won't hurt more than customizing the templates, as that's not well documented.